# How to use a unique_ptr as an argument to a function that requires a base class as parameter

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I'm learning to use managed pointers, specifically unique_ptr.

I've implemented these simple classes, but the function makeAnimalNoise() doesn't work, even though I think I'm passing the correct arguments.

What's wrong with the function makeAnimalNoise()? What should be the correct arguments for this function? Or the definition itself is wrong?

```
class Animal{
public:
  Animal(){
    cout<<"An animal is born"<<endl;
  }
  virtual ~Animal(){
    cout<<"An animal dies"<<endl;
  }
  virtual void doAnimalStuff()=0;
};

class Dog: public Animal{
public:
  Dog(){
    cout<<"A dog is born"<<endl;
  }
  ~Dog() {
    cout<<"A dog dies"<<endl;
  }
  void doAnimalStuff() override {
    cout<<"I'm a dog"<<endl;
  }
};

class Cat: public Animal{
public:
 Cat(){
   cout<<"A cat is born"<<endl;
 }
~Cat() {
   cout<<"A cat dies"<<endl;
 }
void doAnimalStuff() override {
  cout<<"I'm a cat"<<endl;
 }
};

void makeAnimalNoise(unique_ptr<Animal>an){
  an->doAnimalStuff();
}

int main(){
  unique_ptr<Animal>Dog=unique_ptr<Dog>(new Dog());
  unique_ptr<Animal>Cat=unique_ptr<Cat>(new Cat());
  makeAnimalNoise(Dog); //doesn't work here
  makeAnimalNoise(Cat); //doesn't work here
}
```

Comment: A `unique_ptr` is supposed to be *unique* and conveys the idea of ownership. If you're doing something that involves copying them, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to transfer ownership into your `makeAnimalNoise` function. Smart pointers should only be used by the *owner* of the responsibility; you should absolutely *not* replace *all* your code with smart pointers.

Your function should just take a reference:

```
void makeAnimalNoise(Animal& an) {
  an.doAnimalStuff();
}
```

At the call site:

```
makeAnimalNoise(*Dog);
makeAnimalNoise(*Cat);
```

To repeat: smart pointers should only ever appear in APIs when the *ownership* of the pointee is the subject of the API. When only the *value* of the pointee is of interest, use a reference or plain pointer parameter.

To say it in yet another way: smart pointers are a tool for managing responsibility, not for passing values or implementing reference semantics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been experimenting a little bit and I've made the function worked as I wanted. I changed the function's parameters to this: void makeAnimalNoise(Animal*an). And in the main function, I did this: makeAnimalNoise( doggy.get() ). Is this considered to be correct or safe?

Comment: @Drako: That's fine, too. As always, pointer parameters may be passed a null alue, so the have slightly different semantics from reference parameters. Pick whichever works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of `makeAnimalNoise` is declared as passing by value; but `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied; You can move it instead like

```
unique_ptr<Animal> dog(new Dog);
unique_ptr<Animal> cat(new Cat);
makeAnimalNoise(std::move(dog));
makeAnimalNoise(std::move(cat));
```

Comment: Sure you *can* do that. But is that really desired behavior? Should an animal be killed simply for making a noise?

Comment: I think makeAnimalNoise(dog.get()) and makeAnimalNoise(cat.get()) is better and it works fine, but first you have to change the function's parameters.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Well, it depends on OP's intent (i.e. whether the copy/move operations are acceptable). For this question I suppose he is just asking about the usage about `std::unique_ptr`.